# On WCF - OLE DB provider SQLNCLI11 for linked server xxx was unable to begin a distributed transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, linked-server

When I execute a stored procedure which contains a linked server from WCF, I get the error:

```
OLE DB provider \"SQLNCLI11\" for linked server "CLUSTERSQL_DB" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

I have a linked server configured on a server sql server, where I create a stored procedure that makes a query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo]. [TestLinkedServer]
AS
  Select * From [CLUSTERSQL_DB]. [Outbound]. [Dbo]. [Table_1]
GO
```

[CLUSTERSQL_DB] is my linked server.

From **Microsoft SQL Server management studio 17** the stored procedure runs *successfully*.

But, from WCF with Entity Framework 6.1.3 I get the error:

```
OLE DB provider \ "SQLNCLI11 \" for linked server "CLUSTERSQL_DB" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

My Web Service example:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/testLinkedServer", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string testLinkedServer();

public string testLinkedServer()
{
    try
    {
        using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
        {
             Model.MyModel db = new Model.MyModel();
             db.PruebaLinkedServer();
             trans.Complete();
             return "Se Ejecuto el cargue correctamente!" ;
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         return what = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

I have already activated DTC from both servers https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2015/04/ole-db-provider-sqlncli11-linked-server-unable-distributed-transaction/

Is it some configuration on the IIS server where the Web Service is hosted, or configuration of the web.config, or computer configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: When you open SSMS What type of credentials and user are on the login window?  I suspect the connection string in you WCF is different.

Comment: No, the credentials are the same in both SSMS and WCF

Comment: Are SQL Server Authentication

Comment: I still think there is something wrong with the connection string and you are not using the proper options.  Does the WCF work with other queries?

Comment: Yes, apart from that stored procedure there are more, and all are executed correctly, it only fails when calling a stored procedure that contains a linked server.

Comment: web.config connection:
```
<add name="PowerBI" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.PowerBI.csdl|res://*/Model.PowerBI.ssdl|res://*/Model.PowerBI.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=x.x.x.x\PowerBI,7777;initial catalog=X;persist security info=True;user id=XXX;password=XXX\-k\A[p;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Connection string looks ok provided you are not using Window Credential in SSMS login screen.  YOu may be getting a timeout.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b59591c-593c-4e28-bc0a-cd1392efb3ef/entitycommandexecutionexception-timeout?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195586/discussion-between-diegodfrf-and-jdweng).